Infimum of sum and sum of infima involving joint and marginal distributions
Consider measurable spaces $(\Omega_1, \mathcal{F}_1)$, $( \Omega_2, \mathcal{F}_2)$, and let $\mathcal{P}( \mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2 )$ denote the set of all probability measures on it $\mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2$. Let $F, G, f, g$ be non-negative functions such that
$$
\inf_{ \mu \in \mathcal{P}( \mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2 ) } F( \mu) = \inf_{ \mu \in \mathcal{P}( \mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2 ) } f ( \mu \circ \pi^{-1}_1) \tag{1}
$$
and
$$
\inf_{ \mu \in \mathcal{P}( \mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2 ) } G( \mu) = \inf_{ \mu \in \mathcal{P}( \mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2 ) } g ( \mu \circ \pi^{-1}_2). \tag{2}
$$
where $\pi_i : \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2 \rightarrow \Omega_i$ denotes the $i$'th projection.
Is it then true that
$$
\inf_{ \mu \in \mathcal{P}( \mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2 ) } \left( F( \mu) + G ( \mu ) \right) = \inf_{ \mu \in \mathcal{P}( \mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2 ) } f ( \mu \circ \pi^{-1}_1) + \inf_{ \mu \in \mathcal{P}( \mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2 ) } g ( \mu \circ \pi^{-1}_2).
$$
The infimum of a sum is usually larger than the sum of the infima. However, given that the expressions in $(1)$ and $(2)$ depend only on the marginals, is it possible to get an equality? Are additional assumptions necessary?
Remark:
We can further observe that
$$
\inf_{ \mu \in \mathcal{P}( \mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2 ) } f ( \mu \circ \pi^{-1}_1) = \inf_{ \mu_1 \in \mathcal{P} ( \mathcal{F}_1 ) } f( \mu_1 )
$$
and
$$
\inf_{ \mu \in \mathcal{P}( \mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2 ) } g ( \mu \circ \pi^{-1}_2) = \inf_{ \mu_2 \in \mathcal{P} ( \mathcal{F}_2 ) } g( \mu_2 ).
$$

You are essentially asking whether we always have $$\biggl[\inf_{ \mu \in \mathcal{P}( \mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}2 ) } F( \mu)\biggr]+\biggl[\inf{ \mu \in \mathcal{P}( \mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}2 ) } G( \mu)\biggr] = \inf{ \mu \in \mathcal{P}( \mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2 ) } [F( \mu) + G(\mu)], $$ and I see no reason for this to hold in general.

@SangchulLee I agree that what you wrote should not hold in general, hence the additional assumptions in $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Specializing in the case $\Omega_1={0,1}$ and $\Omega_2={0}$, every $\mu\in\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{F}1\otimes\mathcal{F}2)$ is uniquely specified by the value $p=\mu({0,0})$, hence we may regard $F$ and $G$ as functions of $p \in [0,1]$. Even in this case, the question is extremely non-trivial because you are asking when the following holds: $$\inf{p\in[0,1]}[F(p)+G(p)]\stackrel{?}=\inf{p\in[0,1]}F(p)+\inf_{p\in[0,1]}G(p)$$ I can't think of a simple answer for this.

You need some further information how $f$ and $g$ are related to $F$ and $G$. In fact, you could always define $f$ as the constant function
$$
f \equiv \inf F,$$
and similarly for $g$.
Hence, your additional assumptions (1) and (2) are, essentially, void.
